# Convex conjugate of sum of convex functions — infimal convolution

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convolution

I have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+$ defined by $$ f(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x) + f_3(x) - f_4(x) $$ where every $f_i$ is a proper, closed convex function defined over some interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. I would like to minimize $f$

$$ \arg\min\limits_{x \in [a, b]} f(x) $$

The sum of a set of convex functions is convex, so I thought of approaching this by defining $$ g(x) =  f_1(x) + f_2(x) + f_3(x) $$ and $h(x) = f_4(x)$ and minimizing via the difference of convex functions algorithm (DCA) (see [slide 34](http://www.stat.wsu.edu/faculty/bkrishna/FilesMath592/S17/LecNotes/MNNguyen_DCvxFns_Apr122017.pdf)).

$$ \arg\min\limits_{x \in [a, b]} g(x) - h(x) $$

This requires the evaluation of the convex conjugate $g^\star$ of $g$:

$$ g^\star(y) = \mathrm{sup}_{x} \{ \langle x, y \rangle - f(x) \}$$

I know the conjugate functions $f_i^\star$ of each of my constitutive functions $f_i$. However, my understanding is that in general:

$$ (f_1 + f_2 + f_3)^\star (y) \neq (f_1^\star + f_2^\star + f_3^\star)(y)$$

Apparently, extrapolating from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385832/infimal-convolution-on-conjugate-of-the-sum-of-convex-functions) (and reference they give):

$$ (f_1 + f_2 + f_3)^\star(y) = \inf\limits_{x = x_1 + x_2 + x_3} \{ f_1^\star(x_1) + f_2^\star(x_2) + f_3^\star(x_3)\}$$

Alternatively, extracting from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636208/infimal-convolution-g-star-f-1-star-f-2-star), the solution can be obtained via infimal convolution:

$$ (f_1 \Box f_2 \Box f_3)(y) = \sup_{x} \sup_{x = x_1+x_2+x_3} \{ \langle x, y \rangle - f_1(x_1) - f_2(x_2) - f_3(x_3)\}$$

Incidentally, I know the Moreau envelopes of each of the $f_i's$ individually... but I don't know how to resolve the inner $\mathrm{sup}$/obtain $x_1, x_2, x_3$, given some value $x$.... what am I missing?

Related: [The conjugate function of infimal convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132762/the-conjugate-function-of-infimal-convolution)

Answer (score 0):

I'll only attempt to answer part of your question involving the function you call "$g$".

For simplicity, let's consider $f(x):= f_0(x) + f_1(x) + f_2(x)$ when $f_0,f_1,f_2$ are convex.
Then the optimal value of primal problem is
\begin{align}
\nu(P) &:= \min_{x} f(x) = \min_{x,x^1,x^2} \{ f_0(x) + f_1(x^1) + f_2(x^2) : x^1=x,x^2=x\}\\
&\overset{(i)}{=} \max_{\lambda^1,\lambda^2} \min_{x,x^1,x^2} f_0(x) + f_1(x^1) + f_2(x^2) + \langle \lambda^1,x-x^1\rangle + \langle \lambda^2,x-x^2\rangle \\
&= \max_{\lambda^1,\lambda^2} \min_{x} f_0(x) + \langle \lambda^1+\lambda^2,x\rangle + \min_{x^1} f_1(x^1) - \langle\lambda^1,x^1\rangle + \min_{x^2} f_2(x^2) - \langle\lambda^2,x^2\rangle\\
&= \max_{\lambda^1,\lambda^2} -f_0^*(-\lambda^1-\lambda^2) - f_1^*(\lambda^1) - f_2^*(\lambda^2) =: \nu(D)
\end{align}
where $(i)$ follows from strong duality for convex programs.